# Check if radio button is not checked jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radio-button

I'm having a simple form with few different input types. Basically i'm checking if text, textarea, datetime-local had some values and all radiobuttons were checked. That's the code i'm using

```js
$("#submit_button").click(function() {

  var alarm = 0;


  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") alarm = 1;
  })

  $('textarea').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") alarm = 1;
  })

  $('input[type="datetime-local"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") alarm = 1;
  })


  $('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is("checked")) alarm = 1;
  })

  if (alarm == 1) {
    $("#failure").show(200);
    $("#failure").fadeOut(1500);
  } else {
    $("#success").show(200);
    $("#success").fadeOut(1500);
  }
});
```

```css
  #success,
#failure {
  display: none;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="reshenie_radio"><input type="radio" class="reshenie_radio" name="reshenie" value="Пройден">1</label>
<label class="reshenie_radio"><input type="radio" class="reshenie_radio" name="reshenie" value="Не пройден">2</label>
<label class="reshenie_radio"><input type="radio" class="reshenie_radio" name="reshenie" value="Продлен">3</label>

<textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="recommendations" value=""></textarea>

<label style="text-align: center;"><input type="datetime-local" >Date</label>

<label><input type="text" class="avg_score" name="avg_score" width="30" height="50" value="">avg.score</label>


<section id="success">
  <p>Thanks! Everything is ok!</p>
</section>

<section id="failure">
  <p>Please fill all the fields!</p>
</section>

<section id="submit">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" value="send!">
</section>
```

This code checks all the fields fine, but radiobuttons check is not working.

Comment: Your example seems to work though

Comment: You're looping through your radio buttons and the final value of alert is being determined only by the last radio button's state. Also, you can't check all the radio buttons.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).is(":checked")` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can check your radio inputs like this (no need for foreach loop):

```
if(!$('.reshenie_radio').is(':checked')) alarm = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you aren't using `:checked` selector in `is('checked')`

Can also use `:checked` selector and `length`

```
if(!$('.reshenie_radio:checked').length){
   alarm = 1; 
}
```

You can combine all the others also using `filter()`

```
var $emptyInputs = $('input[type="text"], textarea, input[type="datetime-local"]').filter(){
   return !this.value;
});

if($emptyInputs.length){
   alarm = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't add `.each()` for radio input in this code**

By taking your code,
you can do the input checking simply like this,
**https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/wa3n19hw/3/**

Just remove `.each()` 
and add

```
if(!$('input[type="radio"]').is(":checked"))
    {
    alarm = 1;
    }
```